# Is there any MIT licenced jquery pagination plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The famous [jQuery pagination plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination)
is of GPL licence. If I am not wrong to use a GPL licenced software in a product the product must be GPL licenced too. So I am looking for a pagination plugin which is MIT licenced. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Pajinate Plugin is available for download under MIT License. Find info and download at: 
[Pajinate](http://www.w3avenue.com/2010/05/03/pajinate-jquery-pagination-plugin/)

Hope this is what u're looking for :)

Comment: This plugin doesn't have Ajax options. I am using the jQuery pagination plugin for a while now. Because of the licence issue I am trying to replace it. In that regard this Pajinate plugin falls behind quite a bit. But thanks anyways. Worst scenario I will add the missing features to the plugin and submit a patch.